# android madvertise response code 204

Tags: android

I have a problem with implementation of madvertise to my app. I think my code is good and it should works but within 2 days i got over 400 requests and 0 impressions. For every request I got response code 204 and as I can read here [madvertise http api](https://redmine.madvertise.me/projects/madapi/wiki/HTTP_API) it means there is not ads to show but this is weird. Is anyone here using madvertise and can tell me if this is normal ?

Comment: Did you find any fix for that? Or at least an explanation for it?
I see first this: (MadvertiseView$4:697) : Response Code => 204  ; and then this: (MadvertiseView$4:742) : Could not receive a http response on an ad request .

Answer (score 1):

i also use madvertise, and i am experiencing very low fill rates atm (0-2%)... it seems after the christmas holidays, they have some problems getting advertisers. when they get them, they pay very good though, so you shouldn't give up on them and implement some kind of fall back pattern (i tried to describe how i did it [here](http://lessons-learned.posterous.com/how-to-use-admob-and-madvertise-together))